# How do I write a string with absolutely ONE backslash in a text file using R?

Tags: r

I need to write a text file with strings containing absolutely one backslash, which is a path for another software to read. I tried the following code:

```
txtf <- "file.txt"
file <- file(txtf)
writeLines(paste0(' C:\PROGRA~2'), file)
close(file)
```

However, a unique backslash gives the following error:
`Error: '\P' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting "' C:\P"`

If I use two backslashes to try to escape, the output contains two slashes and can not be read by the other software.

How can solve this problem?

Comment: use a forward slash?

Comment: No, I need to use a unique backslash in the path.

Comment: you sure about that? plus `writeLines('C:\\PROGRA~2')` results in `C:\PROGRA~2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the double backslash in the code, it will print a single backslash in the file:

```
txtf <- "file.txt"
file <- file(txtf)
writeLines(paste0(' C:\\PROGRA~2'), file)
close(file)
```

[image]